# ng5-slider change the min and max values based on conditions

Tags: angular, angular9

I have used ng5-slider to show the options range on my website. I have one issue with it. Which is

[image]

default value is "Any". The requirement I have is when I click on 1 up to 5+ "Any" option should not be included in the selected range.

For example, when you click 3 it should only display or mark 1 to 3 but at the moment it will mark all the way from any to 3. if you select "Any" option it should no alow so a range but only that option.

The current behavior

[image]

Expected behavior

[image]

stackbitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng5-slider-range-slider-example-wa1szn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I need your expert's idea.

Comment: Can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Thank you for the response.. @DrashtiDobariya I have updated the question with a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for you to change the minValue of your slider, you need to use `userChange` event in your html. Then, in your userChange method, you need to change the `value` variable from 0 to 1 to be able to move the min-slider to ***1*** from ***ANY***.

I modified the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng5-slider-range-slider-example-cqgxqp?file=src/app/app.component.html) you created to show my solution.

**HTML** - I added the ng5-slider event binding function `userChange` to detect any changes on the slider. For more information about the ng5-slider events, please read [here](https://angular-slider.github.io/ngx-slider/docs).

```
<ng5-slider [(value)]="value" [(highValue)]="highValue" [options]="options" (userChange)="getEvent($event)"></ng5-slider>
```

**TS** - I created the `getEvent` function to get the current highValue of the ng5-slider and then change the `value` variable to 1 if the `highValue` is greater than 0.

```
import {
  Component
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  ChangeContext,
  Options
} from 'ng5-slider';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  value: number = 0;
  highValue: number = 0;
  options: Options = {
    floor: 0,
    ceil: 5,
    translate: (value: number): string => {
      if (value === 5) {
        return '5+';
      }
      if (value === 0) {
        return 'Any';
      }
      return `${value}`;
    },
    combineLabels: (minValue: string, maxValue: string): string => {
      if (minValue === 'Any' && maxValue === 'Any') return minValue;
      if (minValue === '5+' && maxValue === '5+') return maxValue;
      if (minValue === maxValue) return minValue;
      else return minValue + ' - ' + maxValue;
    },
  };

  constructor() {}

  getEvent(e: ChangeContext) {
    if (e.highValue > 0) {
      this.value = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the input. But this works only for the first-time user to change the slider only. but for the later interactions, it won't work. For example, if I move the slider to 3 the first time it will move the low point to 1. but if I move it back to the "Any" option and move the pointer 3 to 4 it will staty at "Any".

Comment: There seems to be an open ticket in their github about this issue. The issue is about the view not updating when the value is updated in the TS file.
https://github.com/angular-slider/ngx-slider/issues/267

Comment: Thank you for the input @dom.macs I will also track the ticket and update if any modification is required.